# ошибка в android studio Execute taskAction

Tags: android-studio

[image]

после builda проекта выскакивает вот такое сообщение об ошибке. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить

Comment: Уважаемый участник, пожалуйста, вставьте в Ваше сообщение код и сообщение об ошибке в виде текста, а не изображения. Почему это нужно: [**1**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), [**2**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Спасибо.

Comment: выложите весь текст styles.